# How can I define a Boolean to a variable?

Tags: python, boolean

I am trying to make a calculator. I have the code that does the operations working, but I am trying to allow the user to keep the calculator running without having to rerun the code. i an trying to assign a Boolean to variable, but python keeps telling me there is a name error, which is the the variable is not defined. Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

I have tried to change the available name but it doesn't do anything.
The code stopped working when it got to the while run == true line.

```
else:
    print('Invalid operator, please run code again')
    run = True
while run == True:

    print(' do you need another problem solved? y/n')
    if input() == y:
        run = True
    elif input() == n:
        run = False
```

I expected the code to ask me if I need another problem solved, but there is a name error.

Comment: First of all, don't put two `input`s at your `if` and `elif`. Instead, assign it to a variable and use it for the comparisons. Secondly, `input() == y` is comparing the `input()` with a _variable_ `y`, which doesn't seem to be defined in your snippet. Use `'y'` and `'n'` instead. Besides, you can wrap your messages like `input('do you need...?')` to take out unnecessary `print`

Comment: You forgot the quotes around `y` and `n`, these are strings. Right now Python is looking for two variables who have these names but they simply do not exist.

Comment: Is run defined out of the else statement? If not, then when else is not called, run will not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is complaining about `y` or `n` it's because you need to surround it with quotes

```
if input() == "y":
   run = True
```

Also, `run == True` is not needed

```
while run:
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
    print('Invalid operator, please run code again')
    run = True
while run:

    print(' do you need another problem solved? y/n')
    inp=input()
    if inp == 'y':
        run = True
    elif inp == 'n':
        run = False
```

you have used input 2 times so your code will wait 2 times for input, use input() once.